# why does string declaring matter in assmebly 8086?

Tags: string, assembly, x86-16

i wanted to write a program that iterate through a string and calculate how many times the letter "C" occured, ( i increase the value of ````BX``` ever time there is a ltter C)
now the code works correctly like this

```
LEA DI, STRING
MOV CX, 6h

FOR:
    CMP CX, 0
    JE END
    cmp [DI], "C"
    jnz siPasDeC
    inc BX 
    siPasDeC:
    INC DI
    dec cx
    jmp FOR     
END: 
    ret
    hlt


STRING DB "CCKCCD"
```

but when i write `STRING DB "CCKCCD"` in the first line the program does sort of an infinite loop. can you tell me why this happened?

PS: is is a best practice to write "ret" and "hlt" every time; because i didn't see people writing it online, but in college we are forced to write it.

Comment: If you put data into the execution path the cpu will try to decode it as instructions and do whatever nonsensical thing it means. No, you don't need the `hlt` because `ret` will already transfer control back to your caller.

Comment: "in college we are forced to write [something completely and utterly useless]". If that's not a single isolated problem in an otherwise stellar program, you should either switch majors or switch colleges, lest you end up graduating with a worthless degree and a lot of incorrect knowledge and bad habits.

Comment: Whoever told you to put `hlt` after `ret` doesn't know what `ret` does. I hate to be that blunt about it but that's a fact.